How to POST using RobinHood Crypto API in Python?
I'm using the new RobinHood crypto API documented here: https://docs.robinhood.com/crypto/trading/#tag/Trading/operation/api_v1_post_crypto_trading_order
I am successful with all GET endpoints, but can't seem to place an order using the POST endpoints. It fails with a verification error, which testing shows usually mean something about the message is wrong. As far as I can tell though, I've followed the documentation exactly.
Here is my code. Is there something that I'm missing?
url = "https://trading.robinhood.com/api/v1/crypto/trading/orders/"
api_path = "/api/v1/crypto/trading/orders/"
http_method_type = "POST"

body = {
    "client_order_id" : "131de903-5a9c-4260-abc1-28d562a5dcf0",
    "side" : "buy",
    "symbol" : "DOGE-USD",
    "type" : "market",
    "market_order_config" : {
        "asset_quantity" : "1"
    }
}    

current_unix_timestamp = int(time.time())

message = (
    f"{API_KEY_ROBIN_HOOD}"
    f"{current_unix_timestamp}"
    f"{api_path}"
    f"{http_method_type}"
    f"{body}"
)

signature = PRIV_KEY.sign(message.encode("utf-8"))

base64_signature = base64.b64encode(signature).decode("utf-8")

PUB_KEY.verify(signature, message.encode("utf-8"))

headers = {
    'x-api-key': API_KEY_ROBIN_HOOD,
    'x-timestamp': str(current_unix_timestamp),
    'x-signature': base64_signature,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)

The entire code is almost identical to my (working) GET functions, except that this is a POST request and that for the first time, the request (and the message) includes a body element.
Do you see something I've overlooked?

I ran into the exactly same problem.
I think the problem is because of json data is not serialized by requests exactly as it should be.
My solution is do the serialization myself and use json string directly in the request.
add the following line:
jsonString = json.dumps(body)
and change request to
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=jsonString)
Hope it helps.

json.dumps() solved my problem too (see the following code). Also, your headers is missing the --data-raw input which contains the order details.
message = f"{api_key}{current_timestamp}{path}{method}{json.dumps(body)}"
command = (f"curl -X \"{method}\" \"{endpoint}\" "
            f" -H 'x-api-key: {api_key}' "
            f" -H 'x-timestamp: {current_timestamp}' "
            f" -H 'x-signature: {base64_signature}' "
            f" -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' "
            f" --data-raw '{json.dumps(body)}' " 
    )

